# Weird issue about audio tag in firefox.

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have an audio tag in my html and it works in chrome. However, I have trouble in FF ver.25.

The source is mp3 but I know FF is now supporting mp3 file. I also copy and paste the mp3 file path on FF address bar and it plays. It just doesn't work in my audio tag.

Symptom:

Audio control bar will appear 1 sec when page first loads but disappear right away. It works in Chrome.

codes:

```
this.audioElement = createElement('audio', {className:'audio',type:'audio/mpeg',        
                    src:'test.mp3'});
this.audioElement.setAttribute('controls',true);
```

I can see the audio tag appear in developer's tool but for some reason it is hiding from the page and I am sure there is no dispay:none for the tag.

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements) on MDN indicates that this is probably an OS-specific problem. Specifically,

> To avoid patent issues, support for MPEG 4, H.264, MP3 and AAC is not built directly into Firefox on desktop and mobile (Android and Firefox OS). Instead it relies on support from the OS or hardware.

The documentation then goes on to list Windows 7+, Windows Vista, Android, and Firefox OS as those OSes which support the audio tag. Do you happen to be using OS X or some other *nix flavor? I know at least on Linux, although Firefox is able to play MP3 files directly via Totem, the audio tag with just an MP3 source has the behavior you describe.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately, it looks like Firefox doesn't support it on OS X yet. The documentation page I linked to references https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=851290, a bug/discussion in deciding which program to use for MP3 playback.

Comment: Just to make sure you could try substituting the MP3 with an Ogg Vorbis file, or adding it as a fall-back source and see if the problem persists.